# how can i import Howler in ionic 1 project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**inside index.html**

```
<script src="../node_modules/howler/dist/howler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**inside app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ion-gallery', 'ngKookies', 
'chart.js', 'angularjs-gauge', 'mediaPlayer', 'ang-drag-drop', 'Howler']);
```

**when using HOWL**

```
var sound = new Howl({
            src: ['sound.webm', 'sound.mp3']
        });
```

**this code gives following error**

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Howl due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Howl' is not available! You either misspelled the 
module name or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../node_modules/howler/dist/howler.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Insted of getting howler.js from the node modules user need to define howlerjs cdn inside the index file

```
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.1.3/howler.js"> 
</script>
```